# Android wear app notifications get disabled when notifications from phone are also disabled

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am building a mobile + wear app. Wear app has its own notification services independent of the phone.

I just noticed that for my app, when I disable the notifications from the phone to wear (on the WearOS app), the in-house notifications of the wear are also disabled. In other words, when I ask my phone to not to send its notification to wear, my wear app does not display its own notifications too!

I was wondering if there is a workaround to this? or is it possible to programmatically detect if the notification from phone to watch is set to disabled on the wearOS app?

Answer (score 1):

You can control how notifications are shared between the wearable and the paired phone in two ways.

From the manifest file:

```
<application>
    ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.notificationBridgeMode"
        android:value="NO_BRIDGING" />
    ...
</application>
```

At runtime:

```
BridgingManager.fromContext(context).setConfig(
        BridgingConfig.Builder(context, false)
                .addExcludedTag("not_this_one")
                .build()
)
```

For more details about the different ways you can control notifications, and how to implement it, see the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/bridger).

Comment: Would one call BridgingManager with a BridgingConfig from the mobile app or the wear app?

Comment: @mdiener From the phone app.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I had tested myself to put it in the Wear app and it worked. I think it would also be more logical, because the phone app might not necessarily know if the Wear app is already installed and/or set-up. Only when the Wear app is installed and once started, preventing bridging makes sense IMHO.